# Row_number() and group by together not working

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wrote below query, I need to know what am I doing wrong. After adding `row_number()`, the output is always this error:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>   00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 22 Column: 32

The SQL Developer tool tip suggested to append `row_number()` in group by together with `Is_Data_Picked`. But as I know `row_number()` is an analytical function to count the each row, and it can't be use in `GROUP BY` clause

When I use `row_number()` inside `GROUP BY`, then it shows the below error

> ORA-30484: missing window specification for this function
>   30484. 00000 -  "missing window specification for this function"
>   *Cause:    All window functions should be followed by window specification, like () OVER ()
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 26 Column: 26

I want to use both "GROUP BY" and "ROW_NUMBER()" in my query.

Kindly help me to rectify this issue and suggest me the solution.

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(DISTINCT Emp_Code) totalEmployees,
         SUM(CASE WHEN pay_code = 999 THEN AMOUNT ELSE '0' END) net_salary,
         SUM(CASE WHEN pay_code = 997 THEN AMOUNT ELSE '0' END) gross_earning,
         SUM(CASE WHEN pay_code = 998 THEN AMOUNT ELSE '0' END) gross_deduction,
         Is_Data_Picked,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (Emp_Code)) AS ROW_NUM
     FROM 
         Xxmpcd_Salary_Detail_Table
     WHERE 
         Prayas_Erp_Org_Id LIKE '302-%'
         AND Yyyymm = '201805'
     GROUP BY 
         Is_Data_Picked, ROW_NUMBER()) mytbl
WHERE
    ROW_NUM < 600 AND ROW_NUM > 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the relevant part of your subquery:

```
SELECT . . . 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (Emp_Code)) AS ROW_NUM
FROM Xxmpcd_Salary_Detail_Table
WHERE Prayas_Erp_Org_Id LIKE '302-%' AND Yyyymm = '201805'
GROUP BY Is_Data_Picked, ROW_NUMBER()
```

You have an error in the first `ROW_NUMBER()` because `Emp_Code` is not in the `GROUP BY`.  You have an error in the second because `ROW_NUMBER()` is not a function.

I could speculate that you intend:

```
SELECT . . . 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Emp_Code) AS ROW_NUM
FROM Xxmpcd_Salary_Detail_Table
WHERE Prayas_Erp_Org_Id LIKE '302-%' AND Yyyymm = '201805'
GROUP BY Is_Data_Picked, Emp_Code
```

If you don't want to aggregate by `Emp_Code`, then you might intend:

```
SELECT . . . 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(Emp_Code)) AS ROW_NUM
FROM Xxmpcd_Salary_Detail_Table
WHERE Prayas_Erp_Org_Id LIKE '302-%' AND Yyyymm = '201805'
GROUP BY Is_Data_Picked
```

Comment: O man,my goodness, so I need to include the Emp_code as well  inside group by clause, thanks so much, I will now take care of this